# Need help figuring out how to limit number of columns in a row of grid view

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello im using a package called [responsive_framework](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework) and im using the [ResponsiveGridView](https://pub.dev/documentation/responsive_framework/latest/responsive_grid/ResponsiveGridView-class.html) and i cant figure out how to limit the number of colums. Ive tried setting `maxRowCount` to 2, but if i do that it adds additional items that are null because i only want 4 but it adds 10, 5 on each row [like this](https://ibb.co/7vFBkc5).

What im looking for is 2 items for each row.

This is the code im using

```
ResponsiveGridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: ResponsiveGridDelegate(
                    crossAxisExtent: 300,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 50,
                  ),
                  itemCount: people.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext bc, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ResponsiveRowColumn(
                        rowColumn: false,
                        children: [
                          ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                            rowFlex: 1,
                            child: Image.network(
                              "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/smartphone-hand-businessman-holding-mobile-phone-cell-arm-template-app-presentation-flat-vector-internet-application-blank-155035117.jpg",
                              scale: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                          ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                            child: Text(people[index].name),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the number of objects, but what you can do is to put the gridview in a container and limit the size which gave the result i wanted.